# Why is this statement true? "Tasks that spend much of their time waiting for external events are generally good candidates for threading."

Tags: python, multithreading

I am very new to the concept of threading. I was going over the content in [this site](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#what-is-a-thread) about threading and came across this claim that `Tasks that spend much of their time waiting for external events are generally good candidates for threading.` May I know why is this statement true.

Comment: because if they're not threaded, they'll make your application unresponsive by blocking it

Answer (score 1):

Threading allows for efficient **CPU** usage. Tasks that spend a lot of time waiting for other events to finish can be put to *sleep* (this means temporarily stopped) with Threading.

By putting a thread to *sleep*, the **CPU** it was being executed with becomes free to execute other tasks while waiting for the thread to be woken up.

The ability  to *sleep* and *wake up* allows:

(1) Faster computation without much overhead

(2) A reduction in wasted computational resources

Answer (score 0):

Alternative viewpoint:

I don't know about Python specifically, but in many other programming languages/libraries, there will be some kind of "async I/O" mechanism, or "select" mechanism, or "event-driven" paradigm that enables a single-threaded program to actively do one thing while simultaneously waiting for multiple other things to happen.

The problem that threads solve comes from the fact that each independent source of input/events typically drives some independent "activity," and each of those activities has its own separate state. In an async/event-driven programming style, the state of each activity must be explicitly represented in some set of variables: When the program receives an event that drives activity *X,* it has to be able to examine those variables so that it can "pick up where it left off" last time it was working on activity *X.*

With threads, part or all of the state of activity *X* can be *implicit* in the *X* thread's *[context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)* (that is, in the value of its program counter, in its registers, and in the contents of its call stack.) The code for a thread that handles one particular activity can look a lot like the pure-procedural code that that we all first learned to write when we were rank beginners—much more familiar looking than any system of "event handlers" and explicit state variables.

The down-side of using multiple threads, is that the familiar look and feel of the code can lull us into a false sense of security—we can easily overlook the possibility of [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), and [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software), and other hazards to which multi-threading exposes us.  Multi-threaded code can be easy to read, but it can be much harder to write it without making subtle mistakes that are hard to catch in testing.